# GPU Frame Capture Warning when loading scene to SceneView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

when i load a scene into the sceneView when i click a button which presents a viewcontroller as a popover i get an error in console when i run the app on my iPhone 6s. On the simulator that doesn´t happen.

> Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Discarded (victim of GPU error/recovery) (IOAF code 5)

and i get this purple warning on runtime in xcode:

[image]

i tried to set the deployment target to the same version as my device but then the simulators and my iPhone doesn´t appear in the target selector.

Thats my code to load the scene:

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ramps.scn")!
sceneView.scene = scene
```

Comment: I'm seeing this warning as well.  According to this post (52509223), you can turn off the prompt.  If it helps, I am running a fairly intensive Scenekit app with a lot of UIKit /threading/etc. - not seeing any loss in FPS or negative visual affects due to the warning.  However, am not seeing the issue where simulators or devices are not visible in the target selector.

Comment: It doesn't help to turn off the prompt if the app is laggy like the issue prompt says